# asp:RegularExpressionValidator Minimum 8 characters and 1 Special Character

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I've tried a couple, I have 
`ValidationExpression="^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-=+])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*#?&]{8,}$" >`  However, I need it to allow all special characters (^,=,+, etc)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
"^(?=.*?[#?!@$%^=+*&-]).{8,}$"
```

You can use '\' to escape character '-'.Or just ensure the '-' is the last character in the special character list or else it will choose a range between the characters around '-'.In your case '*-='.Test the expression [here](http://regexr.com/)

`(?=.*?[#?!@$%^*&=+-])` Alteast 1 special character within [].Add more characters that you want in the minimum set and escape using '\' if needed.

`.{8,}$` Minimum 8 characters

**Match**

```
^testtes
test%tes
testtes+
#?!@&tes
1234567*
testesttesttest1234567&
TEST123!
$TESTTES
$0123121
```

**NoMatch**

```
testtest
testtes1
12345678
testesttesttest12345678
test!
t1@
TEST1234
$012312
```